# mariadb adodb odbc stored proc call seems to cease executing vs native stored proc call

Tags: vba, stored-procedures, odbc, mariadb

I have a stored procedure that inserts 89 rows into table A and 49 rows into table B, as I expect.  Although I notice HeidiSQL shows 150 results 1x1 "SQL error 1062".

However when I call the query via VBA ADODB execution seems to abort early without any error to DBEngine.  I only get 39 records into table A and 6 records into table B, consistently.

My stored proc fetchs rows from a table, inserts two fields into table A, calls some other functions, then inserts values into table B.

Any suggestions?  Is this some weird odbc bug or something with my query?  I don't understand why a stored procedure would function differently when called by ODBC.  I've tried monkying around with the connection string syntax which did not seem to make a difference.

```
Dim conn2 As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd2 As ADODB.Command
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

On Error GoTo err_execute
sConnect = "DSN=hoconet-nms;UID=x;PWD=xxx;"
Set conn2 = New ADODB.Connection
conn2.ConnectionString = sConnect
conn2.Open

sp = "CALL sp_populate_lr_data()"

Set cmd2 = New ADODB.Command
cmd2.ActiveConnection = conn1
cmd2.CommandText = sp

Set rs2 = cmd2.Execute
On Error GoTo 0
Debug.Print "Done populating data "
```

Stored Proc:

```
BEGIN
DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
DECLARE v_hostname, v_westport,v_eastport,v_ringname VARCHAR(50);
DECLARE v_ringid,v_hostid, v_westid,v_eastid INT DEFAULT NULL;

DECLARE rid CURSOR FOR 
   SELECT hostname,lr_name,lr_id,west_port_name, east_port_name FROM parsed_lr_create;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

declare continue handler for sqlexception
    select 'SQLException invoked';

declare continue handler for 1062
    select 'SQL EROR 1062';

declare continue handler for sqlstate '23000'
    select 'SQLSTATE 23000 invoked';

set done = 0;
insert into temp_log (data) values("logging hostname, node_id, west-port-name, west-port-id, east-port-name, east-port-id");

OPEN rid;
get_record: LOOP

    FETCH rid INTO v_hostname, v_ringname,v_ringid,v_westport, v_eastport;

    IF done = 1 THEN
        LEAVE get_record;
    END IF;

   insert into temp_log (data) values (concat("creating lr ", v_ringname, ", ", v_ringid));

    insert into g8032_logical_rings (ring_id, ring_name) values (v_ringid,v_ringname);

    set v_hostid = sp_get_nodeid(v_hostname);
    set v_westid = sp_get_portid(v_hostid, v_westport);
    set v_eastid = sp_get_portid(v_hostid, v_eastport);      

    If (v_hostid = 0 OR v_westid = 0 OR v_eastid = 0) THEN 
        insert into temp_log (data) values (concat("skipping lr config insert ", v_hostname, ", ", v_ringname, ", ",v_westport, ", ", v_eastport));
    ELSE    
        INSERT INTO g8032_logical_rings_configured (ring_id, node_id, west_port_id, east_port_id) values (v_ringid,v_hostid,v_westid,v_eastid);
END IF; 

END LOOP get_record;
CLOSE rid;      
END
```

Appreciate any suggestions you can toss my way.

Comment: Please clarify your issue. Is it the *HeidiSQL shows 150 results 1x1 "SQL error 1062"* or *VBA ADODB execution*?

Comment: Also, check you connections: `conn1` or `conn2` with command?

Answer (score 0):

You might be conflating two ways of running a stored procedure with ADO. Using `CommandText` you can only enter the name of the object (table/view/stored procedure) as a string:

```
Set conn2 = New ADODB.Connection
conn2.ConnectionString = sConnect
conn2.Open

Set cmd2 = New ADODB.Command
cmd2.ActiveConnection = conn2
cmd2.CommandText = "sp_populate_lr_data"
cmd2.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc

Set rs2 = cmd2.Execute
```

Alternatively, you can execute an action directly:

```
Set conn2 = New ADODB.Connection
conn2.ConnectionString = sConnect
conn2.Open

Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = conn2.Execute("CALL sp_populate_lr_data()")
```